# Scroll boxes/bars linked by ref jumpy in React (especially mobile)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scroll, ref

I have built a react component that maps a number of product cards in a horizontal row. When these cards are longer than the screen, overflow occurs and a scroll bar is visible at the bottom of the component allowing the user to scroll left and right along the cards. I also want a scroll bar to be visible above the cards, so I have added an additional div that takes its size from the product cards div (via ref) and presents an empty div with a scroll bar. I have then linked this divs scroll position with the products cards scroll position and vice versa to ensure both are the same. This works, but appears choppy/jumpy when scrolling especially on mobile.

I think maybe this is due to each onScroll event firing multiple times/contradicting each other, but cannot work out how to get this to work. Any help would be really appreciated!

The component that is rendered:

```
<div>
  {checkWidth() ? (
    <div
      className="ui link cards topscroll"
      ref={topScrollRef}
      onScroll={onScroll}
    >
      <div
        style={{
          minWidth: bottomScrollRef.current.scrollWidth,
          overflowX: "scroll",
        }}
      ></div>
    </div>
  ) : (
    ""
  )}
  <div
    ref={bottomScrollRef}
    onScroll={onScroll}
    className="ui link cards bottomscroll"
  >
    {renderList()}
  </div>
</div>
```

And the onScroll event handler:

```
const onScroll = (el) => {
  if (
    el.target.className === "ui link cards topscroll" &&
    bottomScrollRef.current.scrollLeft !== topScrollRef.current.scrollLeft
  ) {
    bottomScrollRef.current.scrollLeft = topScrollRef.current.scrollLeft;
  } else if (
    el.target.className === "ui link cards bottomscroll" &&
    topScrollRef.current.scrollLeft !== bottomScrollRef.current.scrollLeft
  ) {
    topScrollRef.current.scrollLeft = bottomScrollRef.current.scrollLeft;
  }
};
```

note: renderList() returns the products cards

Comment: Any luck finding a better approach?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I actually removed the scrollbar in the end to avoid the issue. Not ideal but I couldn't find another way around it. Sorry

Comment: I can understand. I also suggested my team to get rid of the existing scroll behavior. And thanks for the reply.

Comment: @Helper I have answered below with how I have finally reimplemented. Still not perfect, but a lot less choppy than using the refs as above. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot  @webdog, for getting back to me regarding the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way I found of doing this is using the npm package react-scroll-sync

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scroll-sync

This allows you to sync the two scrolls with minimal jumpyness (not perfect)